# Copying first 100 files from multiple folders to one folder (or deleting the rest)

Tags: scripts, directory, copy, powershell

I've got the following issue. I've got a folder, within this folder there are about 100 different folders, within each of these folders there are about 500 files. I want to only keep the first 100 files from each folder.

I'm looking at while/loops but i can't seem to figure it out. (i've got no scripting skills at all)  i've seen and fiddled with some scripts, but can't get it to grab the first 100 files from every folder.

is there maybe an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First 100 files sorted by what(?) or just random?

Comment: Sorted by name!

Comment: Is using `zsh` an option for you?

Comment: no, sorry......

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filenames don't contain spaces or other strange characters,

You can get the alphabetically first 100 files in a directory with:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | sort |head -n 100
```

but, to get all the other files (the ones you want to "not keep":

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | sort |tail  -n +101
```

Then, replacing `*` with a list of folders, do:

```
for f in * ; do
    cd $f
    # to delete all but the first 100
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | sort |tail  -n +101 | xargs rm
    # or, to copy them elsewhere
    mkdir ../new_$f
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | sort |head -n 100 | \
        xargs cp --target-directory=../new_$f

    # remember to undo initial cd $f
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much all for your help, i've ran the following command: 
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | sort |tail  -n +101 | xargs rm /mnt/d/test/testfolder

But i'm getting back errors;
Cannot remove '/mnt/d/test/testfolder': Is a directory

i'm using the lastest stable built of ubuntu terminal for windows, am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: @brianwhiteee Asking a 2nd Q in the comments is bad - both the 2nd Q and its A will be hidden from AskUbuntu's search.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `zsh`, this kind of thing is easy using its glob qualifiers. Whereas `*` by default matches all non-hidden files (including directories), `zsh` allows you to use globs like `*(.[1,100])` to refer to the first 100 plain files (ordered lexically by name) or `*(.[101,-1])` to match all plain files after the 100th. So for example you could do

```
for d in *(/); do echo rm -- "$d"/*(.[101,-1]); done
```

to (echo) remove all but the (lexically) first 100 files from each subdirectory of the current directory.

If the resulting argument list is too long, you could modify the above to

```
for d in *(/); do print -rN -- "$d"/*(.[101,-1]) | xargs -r0 echo rm -- ; done
```

*Remove the `echo` only once you are absolutely sure it is matching the intended files*.

To copy the first 100 files instead of deleting all the rest, either

```
for d in *(/); do echo cp -t path/to/dest -- "$d"/*(.[1,100]); done
```

or if the argument list is too long

```
for d in *(/); do 
  print -rN -- "$d"/*(.[1,101]) | xargs -r0 echo cp -t path/to/dest/ --
done
```

---

To achieve almost the same in bash in a way that's safe for any legal filename you could use the `set` and `shift` builtins:

```
for d in */; do set -- "$d"*; shift 100; echo rm -- "$@"; done
```

or if the argument list is too long

```
for d in */; do 
  set -- "$d"*; shift 100; printf -- '%s\0' "$@" | xargs -r0 echo rm --
done
```

Note that there is no equivalent of the zsh `(.)` plain file qualifier here - it will match and attempt to remove directories as well if there are any.